# Redirecting all URLs containing a word to a URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying the create a htaccess rule to redirect urls that contain a certain word except for two pages.

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/string
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com
```

---

```
https://www.example.com/string/some-page.html
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/some-page.html
```

---

```
https://www.example.com/string/some-directory/some-page.html
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/some-directory/some-page.html
```

---

```
https://www.example.com/string/some-directory/
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/some-directory/
```

---

EXCEPT NOT REDIRECT THESE TWO PAGES:

```
https://www.example.com/string/checkout/cart/
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/string/checkout/cart/
```

---

and

```
https://www.example.com/string/checkout/onepage/#/steps
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/string/checkout/onepage/#/steps
```

I've already tried all the solutions I could find on Google.I can't seem to even get the basics to work!

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

**EDITED TO ADD CURRENT REWRITE RULES BELOW**

```
    ModPagespeed on
    AllowOverride None
    AllowOverrideList None
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorDocument 401 default
    ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
    ErrorDocument 403 "Authorization Required"
    ErrorDocument 500 /error-500.html
    Options All -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
    Options All

    SSLOptions

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]     
    RewriteRule ^(.*)local.xml$ - [F,L] 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]    
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.111
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (es) [NC]
#RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/mx [L]

    ##### Block unwanted Crawler Bots that clog your server #####

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 80legs [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]

    ##############################################################
    ## Remove Bad Bots from crawling ##
    # IF THE UA STARTS WITH THESE
    # Block spambots
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(aesop_com_spiderman|alexibot|backweb|bandit|batchftp|bigfoot) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(black.?hole|blackwidow|blowfish|botalot|buddy|builtbottough|bullseye) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(cheesebot|cherrypicker|chinaclaw|collector|copier|copyrightcheck) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(cosmos|crescent|curl|custo|da|diibot|disco|dittospyder|dragonfly) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(drip|easydl|ebingbong|ecatch|eirgrabber|emailcollector|emailsiphon) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(emailwolf|erocrawler|exabot|eyenetie|filehound|flashget|flunky) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(frontpage|getright|getweb|go.?zilla|go-ahead-got-it|gotit|grabnet) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(grafula|harvest|hloader|hmview|httplib|httrack|humanlinks|ilsebot) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(infonavirobot|infotekies|intelliseek|interget|iria|jennybot|jetcar) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(joc|justview|jyxobot|kenjin|keyword|larbin|leechftp|lexibot|lftp|libweb) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(likse|linkscan|linkwalker|lnspiderguy|lwp|magnet|mag-net|markwatch) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(mata.?hari|memo|microsoft.?url|midown.?tool|miixpc|mirror|missigua) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(mister.?pix|moget|mozilla.?newt|nameprotect|navroad|backdoorbot|nearsite) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(net.?vampire|netants|netcraft|netmechanic|netspider|nextgensearchbot) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(attach|nicerspro|nimblecrawler|npbot|octopus|offline.?explorer) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(offline.?navigator|openfind|outfoxbot|pagegrabber|papa|pavuk) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(pcbrowser|php.?version.?tracker|pockey|propowerbot|prowebwalker) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(psbot|pump|queryn|recorder|realdownload|reaper|reget|true_robot) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(repomonkey|rma|internetseer|sitesnagger|siphon|slysearch|smartdownload) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(snake|snapbot|snoopy|sogou|spacebison|spankbot|spanner|sqworm|superbot) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(superhttp|surfbot|asterias|suzuran|szukacz|takeout|teleport) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(telesoft|the.?intraformant|thenomad|tighttwatbot|titan|urldispatcher) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(turingos|turnitinbot|urly.?warning|vacuum|vci|voideye|whacker) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(libwww-perl|widow|wisenutbot|wwwoffle|xaldon|xenu|zeus|zyborg|anonymouse) [NC,OR]
    #
    ## STARTS WITH WEB
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^web(zip|emaile|enhancer|fetch|go.?is|auto|bandit|clip|copier|master|reaper|sauger|site.?quester|whack) [NC,OR]
    #
    ## ANYWHERE IN UA -- GREEDY REGEX
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(craftbot|download|extract|stripper|sucker|ninja|clshttp|webspider|leacher|collector|grabber|webpictures).*$ [NC]
    #
    RewriteRule . - [F,L]
    #
    ## Useragents starting with
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^atraxbot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Azureus [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^geohasher [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PycURL [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Python-urllib [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^research-scan-bot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sosospider [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^xenu [NC,OR]
    #
    ## User agents contains string
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*casper [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR]    
    #
    ## Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in the HTTP Request
    #
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D).* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in the Referer Variable of the HTTP Request
    ## RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)(<|>|'|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
    ## Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in any cookie associated with the HTTP Request
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*(<|>|'|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Block out use of illegal characters in URI or use of malformed URI
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|">|"<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999}.* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Block out  use of empty User Agent Strings
    ## NOTE - disable this rule if your site is integrated with Payment Gateways such as PayPal
    ## RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
    ## Block out  use of illegal or unsafe characters in the User Agent variable
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|'|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Measures to block out  SQL injection attacks
    #
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|'|"|"|'|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Block out  reference to localhost/loopback/127.0.0.1 in the Query String
    #
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR]
    #
    ## Block out  use of illegal or unsafe characters in the Query String variable
    #
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|'|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
    #
    ########## Begin - File injection protection, by SigSiu.net
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    ########## End - File injection protection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache docs for htaccess can be tricky to figure out in the beginning.  Htaccess has been around since the first web server and morphed along the way into what we fiddle with now.  I've had to figure out things like this very many times. There are surely several ways to accomplish what you want, which makes it even more confusing. Here's a `.htaccess` file that should do the trick for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow my ln -s links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# pass everything with /string/checkout as-is
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/string/checkout/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /string/checkout/%1 [END]

# remove "/string" from all other URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/string/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1 [R,L]
```

It is possible to handle just the 2 pages you requested but it is likely that you probably need to allow everything to pass through the `/string/checkout` URI path.

You may not need the `RewriteBase /` and `Options +FollowSymlinks` lines, but I needed them when I gave it a spin on my dev server.

- The `[END]` flag on the first rule means to stop all further rule
  processing, which safeguards your `/string/checkout` URIs from
  getting mangled by the second rule, which strips out the `/string`
  portion of all matching URIs that make it to that point.
- The `[R,L]` flags on the second rule mean to do a redirect `[R]` and 
  to make this the last `[L]` rule processed in this rule set.
- The `%1` is replaced by whatever matches the regular expression
  `(.*)` in the first part of each rule.

There's a lot going on here in only a few lines, so if you need more info you shud wade through the pertinent Apache docs:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

I uploaded a source demo using simple HTML here:

https://github.com/ByteSlinger/Htaccess-Rewrite-Demo

Testing and demoing this can be tricky if you don't have a root website to use, so here's a live demo on a subdirectory:

http://dev.byteslinger.net/htaccessdemo/

Comment: I couldn't get either method to work. So I edited my question to show the  current rewrite rules I have. Please take a look at my edited question.

Comment: I checked ByteSlinger as correct although I couldn't get it to work in my application, it obviously works. Thanks

Comment: I used ur full .htaccess file on my server with a few minor tweaks.  If I insert my 2 rulesets near the beginning of ur file, then it works fine (mostly ... index gets wiped out ...).  But if I put my rulesets at the end then it no longer works.  It's more work than I have time for, but you may have to pull out some lines and figure out which rulesets are overlapping or fracking with each other.  There a couple of htaccess tester sites out there that I've used before to debug these files.  https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+tester.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, Just a process of deduction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative lookahead expression this can be done in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^string(?:/(?!checkout/.)(.*))?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# remaining rule go below this line
```

Make sure this rule is your top rule and you test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.